# How do I update values in percentage with 2 decimals in SQL? Mine returns zero

Tags: mysql

How do I update values in percentage with 2 decimals in SQL? I am using below query but it returns zero:

```
update dr.datatemp10
    set DR1_DPO=(DR1Transactions_QC*8-Dr1_errors)/(DR1Transactions_QC*8)*100.00
```

Note: I am trying to fetch values from column DR1Transactions_QC and Dr1_errors to update the column DR1_DPO. Please help.

Comment: `I am using below query but it returns zero` Query returns zero?

Comment: what are the values of DR1Transactions_QC ,Dr1_errors and what is the expected result ?

Comment: Please! Don't forget `where` clause!

Comment: If you want two decimals, then define the column using fixed point decimals (`decimal(8,2)` for example).

Answer (score -1):

try to get the right value with 2 decimals in another variable and make sure of its displays, it's helpful to use the function round

```
$value = round((DR1Transactions_QC*8-Dr1_errors)/(DR1Transactions_QC*8)*100.00,2);
echo $value;
$request = "update dr.datatemp10 set DR1_DPO=".$value;
```

hopeful this will help you

Comment: What is the relevance of $value here? do I simply run this query or I need to insert some variables?

Comment: $value will get a value with 2 decimals as you want, because we use `round($var,$definition)` where $definition is 2